# how to set timeout on a call using akka.http.javadsl.Http

Tags: java, akka-http

Im on  a project that is using: akka.http.javadsl.Http;

Im modyfing a piece of code that used to work well,
now the problem is the http call i make need to wait more for the response,
so i have to set the timeout, but even if i tried to read the documentation i didnt find any example.

```
        Http http = Http.get(context().system());

        CompletionStage<HttpResponse> response = http.singleRequest(HttpRequest.create(url), materializer);
        
        CompletionStage<JsonNode> result = response.thenCompose( res -> {
            if (res.status().intValue()!=200) {
                ....
```

i need to do something like "http.setTimeout(5000)"

or " .. = http.singleRequest(HttpRequest.create(url), materializer,5000);"

with 5000 as number of milliseconds to wait for the response before to go on timeout.

Can you help me?

Comment: Doest [this](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/timeouts.html#client-timeouts) or [that](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/akka-response-body-to-string#1-strict-request) help?